# NHibernate: Better to store reference to another Entity or the entity's ID?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nhibernate

New to NHibernate and C#.

I have these two classes:

```
User //Simplified version
{
    private long _id;
    private String _username; // unique
    private ISet<Role> _roles;

    //Properties
}
```

and

```
Role
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;

    //Properties
}
```

Is it better to store a reference to the `Role` class (as done above) or just store the IDs of the `Role` class (so: `private ISet<Long> _roles`)? Why?

Any pros and cons I should be aware of?

Comment: As long as there are reasonable and objective arguments for one or the other, it is **not opinion-based**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly NHibernate is [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

> ... In object-oriented programming, data management tasks act on object-oriented (OO) objects that are almost always non-scalar values. For example, consider an address book entry that represents a single person along with zero or more phone numbers and zero or more addresses. This could be modeled in an object-oriented implementation by a "Person object" with attributes/fields to hold each data item that the entry comprises: the person's name, a list of phone numbers, and a list of addresses. The list of phone numbers would itself contain "PhoneNumber objects" and so on. The address book entry is treated as a single object by the programming language (it can be referenced by a single variable containing a pointer to the object, for instance). Various methods can be associated with the object, such as a method to return the preferred phone number, the home address, and so on....

Secondly - is it better to do A or B... would be more dependent on a use case.

But I can say, *(based on my experience)* that if:

- there **are** two objects in our domain, e.g. `User` and `Role`
- we **can** represent them as `one-to-many and`many-to-one` *(bidirectional mapping)*

I will always map them via references. Because there is no benefit to map them as `long ReferenceId` and `ISet<long> ReferenceIds`.

The only use case where to map just IDs (I can imagine) would be to use it in stateless session to get some huge amount of data. But even in this scenario, we can use projections.

Answer (score 1):

"Storing" the Ids doesn't sound like a good idea to me. In fact, the database schema would look the same, so it's not a difference how you store data, just how you design your classes. And ids aren't very useful in contrast to actual objects.

Here some pros and cons anyway:

Advantage of mapping IDs

- You could serialize your entity more easily, because the object graph ends here and you wouldn't end up in serializing too many objects. (Note that serializing entities has some other issues and is not recommended in many cases.)

Advantages of mapping objects:

- You can easily navigate to the objects without DB interaction thus taking full advantages of using an ORM (maintainability).
- You can make use of batch size, which avoids the N+1 problem without optimizing data access in your problem domain (performance and maintainability)

Answer (score 1):

When you build the domain model it should use the proper references rather than using id values,

Advantages,

1. You can have a proper domain model, so programming becomes easier (if you want to get list of role names per user, then in domain model it's pretty straightforward while if you have id list then it
2. Easy to query (using either QueryOver / Linq or HQL)
3. Efficient SQL (if you want to load the user and roles, you can use Future to load all in a single query if you use references, but if you use Id then you have to use multiple queries)

I don't see any disadvantages of using references as long as mapping is correct.

However I'd rather use Id of entities or a DTO stored if the requirement is to store a object over multiple sessions. For example if you want to store the user in the Web Session object, I would not store any domain objects there rather I'd store the Id or a DTO object.